# Try/Catch: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, java-ee, memória, jboss, memory-leaks

Estou com um problema bastante grave na minha aplicação web, e depois de muita pesquisa, descobri que o erro

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Pode estar sendo causado por `try/catch` com `catch` sem nada no código, semelhante ao seguinte:

```
try {
    //FAZ ALGUMA COISA
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Gostaria de saber como é possível tratar isso SEM interromper o código (mostrando uma tela ou mensagem de erro) e SEM alterar o funcionamento da aplicação.

Ou caso tenham ideia do que mais pode causar esse problema e o que pode resolvê-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Não é para tratar este tipo de erro, este é o erro mais grave que pode acontecer com sua aplicação e ele é intratável nela, isto ocorre por erros graves de programação ocorridos até mesmo em outros lugares ou por acúmulo de erros. Tem que descobrir o que está causando isto, mas o local que dá esse erro é só sintoma, não adianta tentar fazer algo aí, tem que ver a origem.

O erro nunca é causado pelo que achou nas suas pesquisas. O que deu pra perceber é que está fazendo coisas aleatórias e isto vai dificultar até achar o problema. Pra ser bem sincero acho que terá que contratar alguém que seja capaz de achar o erro. Pode ser muitos e ser bem complicado resolver.

O que é certo é que não temos como ajudar nos problemas específicos, só te orientar sobre a solução real.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

> descobri que o erro java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space pode estar sendo causado por try/catch com catch sem nada no código, semelhante ao seguinte:

Com certeza a causa do erro `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` não é esta.

> Gostaria de saber como é possível tratar isso SEM interromper o código (mostrando uma tela ou mensagem de erro) e SEM alterar o funcionamento da aplicação.

Isto também não é possível. O erro `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` ocorre quando sua aplicação não tem mais memória disponível no heap. Ter memória disponível no heap é essencial para sua aplicação Java funcionar, não tem como contornar isto em tempo de execução.

O que você precisa fazer é identificar no seu código o ponto (ou os pontos) que deve estar consumindo muita memória e fazer a devida otimização. Você também pode optar por aumentar o tamanho da memória *heap* disponível para sua aplicação com o argumento `Xms`, caso sua aplicação "naturalmente" consuma muita memória (e não esteja consumindo muita memória por falha de programação).

Por exemplo, o `-Xmx1024m` aumentar para até 1024MB a área de heap disponível:

```
export JVM_ARGS="-Xmx1024m"
```

A aplicação da opção `-Xmx` vai variar conforma a aplicação, pois esta opção pode ser um argumento da execução de um jar, pode estar dentro do servidor da aplicação, pode estar na variável de ambiente (como no exemplo acima), etc. Vai depender de como está iniciando sua aplicação atual.